# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb R^3} \exp(-x^tAx + b^tx) \,\lambda_3(dx)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I want to calculate $\int_{\mathbb R^3} \exp(-x^tAx + b^tx) \,\lambda_3(dx)$ for $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1  & 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad b= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$
I would like to ask if my solution is correct and if there is a faster/better way.

Solution:
We see that $A$ is a positive definite symmetric covariance matrix.

Call $B := 2A$ and write $$-x^tAx + b^t x = -\frac{1}{2}(x^tBx - 2b^tx) = -\frac{1}{2}\left((x-B^{-1}b)^t B(x-B^{-1}b) -b^tB^{-1}b\right)$$
so we get $$\int_{\mathbb R^3} \exp(-x^tAx + b^tx) \,\lambda_3(dx) = \exp(b^tA^{-1}b) \int_{\mathbb R^3} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left((x-B^{-1}b)^t B(x-B^{-1}b)\right)\right) \,\lambda_3(dx) $$
Now the integral is the integral over the $3$-dimensional centered normal distribution and evaluates to $$\int_{\mathbb R^3} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left((x-B^{-1}b)^t B(x-B^{-1}b)\right)\right) \,\lambda_3(dx) = (2\pi)^{3/2}\det B = (8\pi)^{3/2} \det A$$
So it now only remains to compute $\det A$ and $A^{-1}$:
$$\det A = 1, \quad A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 & -2 \\ -1 & -2 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$
hence 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^3} \exp(-x^tAx + b^tx) \,\lambda_3(dx) = \exp(b^t A b) (8\pi)^{3/2} = e^{10} (8\pi)^{3/2}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my calculations the integral has the value $e^{5/2}\pi^{3/2}$. I give two different answers. It is a matter of taste which one is the faster/better one.

**Answer 1**. This is essentially your solution. I omit the matrix $B$. Since
\begin{equation*}
 -\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}A^{-1}b\right)^{t}A\underbrace{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}A^{-1}b\right)}_{=y} + \dfrac{1}{4}x^tA^{-1}x = -y^{t}Ay +\dfrac{1}{4}x^tA^{-1}x .
\end{equation*}
I get
\begin{equation*}
I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\exp(-x^{t}Ax+b^{t}x )\,\mathrm{d}x_{1}\mathrm{d}x_{2}\mathrm{d}x_{3} = \exp(\dfrac{1}{4}x^tA^{-1}x)\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\exp(-y^{t}Ay)\,\mathrm{d}y_{1}\mathrm{d}y_{2}\mathrm{d}y_{3}
\end{equation*}
The next substitution is $y = Qz$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix with columns that are orthonormal eigenvectors to $A$. Then $\det Q = 1$ and
\begin{equation*}
y^{t}Ay =\lambda_{1}z_{1}^{2}+\lambda_{1}z_{2}^{2}+\lambda_{1}z_{3}^{2}
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_{k}, k=1,2,3$, are positive eigenvalues to $A$.
Now we return to the integral
\begin{gather*}
I = \exp(\frac{1}{4}10)\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\exp(-\lambda_{1}z_{1}^{2}-\lambda_{2}z_{2}^{2}-\lambda_{3}z_{3}^{2})\,\mathrm{d}z_{1}\mathrm{d}z_{2}\mathrm{d}z_{3} =\\[2ex] e^{5/2}\dfrac{\pi^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}}} = e^{5/2}\dfrac{\pi^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\det(A)}} = e^{3/2}\pi^{3/2}
\end{gather*}
where I have used that $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}=\det(A) = 1.$

**Answer 2**. In this solution completing the square is essential.
Put $x^t = \left(x_1\, x_2\, x_3\right)$. Then
\begin{equation*}
-x^{t}Ax+b^{t}x = -2x_1^2+2x_1x_2-2x_2^2-2x_2x_3-x_3^2+x_1+2x_2+3x_3 = -2u_1^2-\dfrac{3}{2}u_2^2-\frac{1}{3}u_3^2  +\dfrac{5}{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{array}{lclclclcl}
u_1&=&x_1&-&\dfrac{1}{2}x_2&&&-&\dfrac{1}{4}\\[2ex]
u_2&=&&&x_2&+&\dfrac{2}{3}x_3&-&\dfrac{5}{6}\\[2ex]
u_3&=&&&&&x_3&-&2
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
With notation from answer 1 I get
\begin{equation*}
I =e^{5/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\exp\left(-2u_1^2-\dfrac{3}{2}u_2^2-\frac{1}{3}u_3^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}u_{1}\mathrm{d}u_{2}\mathrm{d}u_{3} = e^{5/2}\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{3/2}}\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1/3}} = e^{3/2}\pi^{3/2} .
\end{equation*}